# can not set drop down value on post success

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and I am creating a edit page and I load data through success callback on post. But my dropdown values are not loaded while my text values are coming  fine. All the recieving data are fine, I don't know why drop down values are not get set?

```
    $http.post('article/get-article.php',{id: id})
.success(function(response){
    $scope.article = response[0];
  });

//My category drop down html
<select class="form-control"  name="category" ng-model="article.category" ng-options ="art.id as art.title for art in categories"  required >
        </select>
```

**EDIT**
*I am attaching my full controller code*

```
myApp.controller('editArticle', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams', 'editArt',function($scope,$http, $routeParams, editArt){
$scope.article = {};
$scope.statusList = [{title: 'New', id: 1, role: "Author"},{title: 'Approved', id: 2, role: "Admin"},{title: 'Rejected', id: 3, role: "Admin"}];
$scope.categories = [{title: 'Cricket',id: 1},{title: 'Football',id: 2 },{title: 'Tennis',id: 3},{title: 'Golf',id: 4,}];

var id = $routeParams.id;
article = "";
//$scope.article = editArt.getData('article/get-article.php',{id: id});
$http.post('article/get-article.php',{id: id})
.then(function(response){
    $scope.article = response.data[0];
    //$scope.article.category = response.data[0].category;
    console.log(response.data);
  });
}]);
```

Comment: what is the value of categories object ?? and what is response[0] value?

Comment: `$scope.categories = [{title: 'Cricket',id: 1},{title: 'Football',id: 2 },{title: 'Tennis',id: 3},{title: 'Golf',id: 4,}];`

Comment: `author_id
 
 "3175"
category
 
 "1"
content
 
 "God of cricket"
id
 
 "3"
image
 
 "master-oogway-quote.jpg"
status
 
 "1"
title
 
 "Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar"`

I copied it from firebug, this is the object I recieved from response[0]

Comment: What is the value of $scope.article.category?

Comment: Displaying through console.log() inside then it shows "1" correct value. But out side post, it showing undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @Deep Comment on check whether category is string or number is done the trick

```
$scope.article.status = parseInt(response.data[0].status);
$scope.article.category = parseInt(response.data[0].category);
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 obvious issues in your code which might be causing the problem:

1. You are assigning the `response` directly to your scope varibale. The response data in `$http` call is wrapped and the actual data is available as `response.data` instead of `response`. So ou should replace `response` with `response.data`

   ```
   $http.post('article/get-article.php',{id: id})
     .then(function(response){
       $scope.article = response.data[0];
     });
   ```
2. Your categories doesn't seem to being set in HTML

The most probable reason in your case seem to be #1 above

Comment: I tested with console.log(response). Its fine and if I use response.data it says undefined. I set the catogories intially in the HTML. since it not relevant to this part I didn't place it.  `$scope.categories = [{title: 'Cricket',id: 1},{title: 'Football',id: 2 },{title: 'Tennis',id: 3},{title: 'Golf',id: 4,}];`

Comment: Try it with `.then` method instead of `.success`. I have updated the code above

Comment: If I used `.then`, a small twist I am getting the same data in the response.data[0] as you said, but still it's not getting assigned to my drop down.

Answer (score 0):

So edit should be done something like this.

1) Use $http get instead of post. Pass Id to it and get the response. (Make the get call on every page load so that you have the updated data)

2) Your HTML is correct. But I dont see you posting any data. You need to post $scope.article object to get the updated value of it using get in edit case

Comment: fine, even if I use `get` I have to set it in success right, thats the problem I am having.

Comment: It would be nice, if you can help me with a code snippet

Comment: Can you just post what is response.data[0]?

Comment: `author_id "3175" category "1" content "God of cricket" id "3" image "master-oogway-quote.jpg" status "1" title "Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar" ` I copied it from firebug, this is the object I recieved from response[0]

Comment: You are doing $scope.article = response.data[0]; when the data you want to assign is in $scope.article = response[0]

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below plunker code.

https://plnkr.co/edit/HSAJc1kcaPr2YAdZXQzy?p=preview

As per the provided html option will be only set when the ng-model article.category has the id value.

```
$scope.article.category = '1';
```

check your response and properly assigned the ng-model

Comment: Bro, the concern here is that its not working inside post

Comment: Oh, OK let me have  a look once again with post call.

Comment: Please check the updated example,could not get a success post call so tried with error callback , i am able to set the select box properly. The one things i can see is if var id = 1 , the drop down is selected but if it is var id = "1" than it is not. Just check if category in your response is string or number.